# matplotlib.pyplot.Figure.show freezes instantly

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Following strange problem: This code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 0, 3])
fig.show()
```

causes the graph window (backend: tkagg) to freeze as soon as it opens, however this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 0, 3])
plt.show()
```

opens the graph window (also tkagg) as expected. I tried debugging, but attaching Visual Studio to `python.exe` and hitting pause causes VS to crash and `python_d.exe` always complains `cannot import name 'multiarray'`. I did a fresh reinstall of python (purging all files, installing python 3.6.3 x86_64, pip install matplotlib) and the behavior continues. **What is causing this behavior? Is there a way to fix it?**

More information about my system: I'm running Windows 8.1 x86_64 with Python v3.6.3:2c5fed8 x86_64 and matplotlib 2.1.0 (rev-id b392d46466e98cd6a437e16b52b3ed8de23b0b52).

**Solution:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 0, 3])

root = fig.canvas._tkcanvas.winfo_toplevel() # Get tkinter root
fig.show()
root.mainloop() # Enter mainloop
```

Comment: Replace fig.show with plt.show in the first example. I've seen this before, not sure what the cause is. Probably has to do with the thread things get run on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see quite the same behaviour, but I'm testing on Python 3.5, matplotlib 2.1, and Ubuntu 16.04. When I run your first version, I see the plot window open very briefly, and then close itself.

However, if you look at the documentation, it's not too surprising that the behaviour of the two examples is different. You're calling two different `show()` methods.

In the first version, you're calling [`Figure.show()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.show):

> If using a GUI backend with pyplot, display the figure window.

In the second version, you're calling [`pyplot.show()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show):

> Display a figure... In non-interactive mode, display all figures and block until the figures have been closed...

I stepped through the second method, and it's basically equivalent to this:

```
fig.show()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

So I'm not sure why it's freezing on you, but it probably wasn't what you wanted in the first place. Create the subplots if you want, but call `plt.show()` at the end.

Comment: @DonKirby. It's not strictly crashing according to OP, just freezing. Probably because main loop is never run.

Comment: Changed the wording from crashing to freezing. Thanks, @MadPhysicist.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I figured out a solution for me. If I look into `matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py` for `FigureManagerTkAgg.show`, it doesn't seem to call the tkinter root's `mainloop()`. I added the solution code to my question.